Pornography, Incest, Adultery, Infidelity, Unfaithful, doing bad acts in the title of mutual consent
Now a days, Most people receptive to pornography, social media, lust and acts they commit accept the idea of having more than one sexual relation with social media in their favor portraying multi sexual relations as normal. For those who know holy scriptures, puranas, vedas, This actually is sinning or maybe kali effect. say, coitus happens on mutual consent and liking, I have seen cases like these and some are completely wrong. Does all these fall under sinning like there are consequences for everything you do or Is this the new normal that world around me just putting words in my mouth. Please explain what should I believe, give it straight and simple
